# Why does not \centering work on a table, while \begin{center} does?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I cannot get my grips around the different effects of \begin{center} and \centering when used on tables (not inside tables). The MWE should explain the issue clearly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\\
\emph{Definite benefit} & \emph{Definite cost} \\
Self-respect & Expense \\
\\
\emph{Possible benefit} & \emph{Probable cost} \\
Compensation & Trauma \\
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

works to center, but not

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\\
\emph{Definite benefit} & \emph{Definite cost} \\
Self-respect & Expense \\
\\
\emph{Possible benefit} & \emph{Probable cost} \\
Compensation & Trauma \\
\\
\end{tabular}
}

Why?

\end{document}
```

[image: First table centered, the other one not.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A paragraph is set using the settings at the *end* of the paragraph. You have a `{}` group around the centering which means that its settings are discarded before the paragraph ends. Include a blank line before the `}` or rely on a surrounding environment such as `table`.

Comment: That works perfectly… but I'm not sure I fully understand. Why is the \centering discarded, alternatively why does the blank line make the \centering matter?

Comment: Is it because the paragraph is bound by the {}?

Comment: @trmdttr all local assignments (including those made by `\centering` are discarded at the end of a group. So you want the centred paragraph to _end_ within the scope of those assignments, which means that it has to be before the `}` or don't have a `{}` group at all.

Comment: Isn't there only one paragraph inside `{\centering ... }`? When is `\centering` discarded?

Comment: @FangJing you can have as many paragraphs as you like where you have `...` it might be the whole document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm actually referring to the instance of `\centering` in the MWE, and used `...` to represent the content there. Specifically, my questions are regarding `{\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\\
\emph{Definite benefit} & \emph{Definite cost} \\
Self-respect & Expense \\
\\
\emph{Possible benefit} & \emph{Probable cost} \\
Compensation & Trauma \\
\\
\end{tabular}
}`

Comment: @FangJing OK then I don't understand your comment, yes there is just one paragraph, consisting of the tabular `\centering` is a local declaration so its effect ends at the `}` so there are no paragraph ends within its scope, so it does nothing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah I think I understand now. Because the `tabular` environment does not constitute a paragraph, so there is no paragraph ending in the entire `{}` group in which `\centering` appears in the MWE. In contrast, a `table` environment constitutes a paragraph, so a `\centering` will show. Am I right?

Comment: @FangJing a `tabular` is like a big letter so `{\centering \begin{tabular}..\end{tabuar}}` is like `{\centering A}` and in both cases the paragraph ends after the `}`